# How to serialize model's all related models using pydantic

Tags: python, serialization, django-orm, pydantic, tortoise-orm

**Setup (tortoise-orm models):**

```
class Hand(BaseModel):
    id: int
    fingers: fields.ReverseRelation["Finger"]


class Finger(BaseModel):
    id: int
    hand: fields.ForeignKeyField(model_name="models.User", related_name="fingers", null=True)
```

Let's say that we have an id of a hand, and we want to **return its all related fingers** to the user. How should I create **pydantic** model for it, and how should I query all fingers mentioned?

**What I've tried so far (with no luck):**

#1

```
    Fingers_dto = pydantic_queryset_creator(Finger)
    hand = await Hand.get(pk=id).prefetch_related("fingers")
    return await Fingers_dto.from_queryset(hand.fingers)
```

#2

```
    Fingers_dto = Finger.create_query_set()
    hand = await Hand.filter(pk=id)
    await hand.fetch_related("fingers")
    return await Fingers_dto.from_queryset(hand.fingers)
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this I had to do following:

```
Fingers_dto = pydantic_queryset_creator(Finger)
hand = await Hand.get(pk=id)
return await Fingers_dto.from_queryset(hand.fingers.all())
```

Comment: What if you would like to return a list of hands, with each a list of fingers?

Comment: `hands = await Hand.all().prefetch_related("fingers")` that would make the job I guess, then you will get simply a list of hands with each a list of fingers. However you can also firstly fetch all hands and then if needed fetch all of their fingers, like so:

`hands = await Hands.all()
hands.fetch_related("fingers")`